# how to add multiple map markers in android app

Tags: google-maps-android-api-2

i have Google map displayed complete in my app. but the problem is how to add multiple map markers in my app. for different locations? and i am try some coded from here to my problem but not work..

like this

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {




    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }


    private void setUpMap() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call

```
LatLng latLng = new LatLng(double_lat, double_long);
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
```

how many times you want

Comment: i don't no but multiple times may be

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add and show markers on your map there tree good steps to do it :
1 - Create an ARRAYList(MarkerOptions) MarkerList
2 - Create a function that add marker to MarkerList
3-  Create a function that add all marker from MarkerList to the map.

After Creating MarkerList , this is addMarkerToList()

```
public  void  AddMarkerToList(double latitude,double longitude , String Name)
{
    //Add Marker using Object
    //we put just latitude and longitude and tilte of the marker 
    MarkerList.add(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(latitude,longitude)).title(Name));
```

In the end this is the last function :

```
public void showMarker()
{
for (int i=0 ;i<MarkerList.size();i++) {
mMap.addMarker(MarkerList.get(i));
}
}
```